# Change ordering of includes in AC_CHECK_HEADER

Tags: c++, autoconf

I have an issue where I need to check for the existence of a header file, rose.h.
When using AC_CHECK_HEADER, headers are included after a series of other (default, I presume) headers.
One such header is sys/stat.h.
Unfortunately, the rose.h header file (which I have no control over, in any way) *must* be included *before* the sys/stat.h header is included:

```
#if defined(_SYS_STAT_H)
#error "sys/stat.h should not have been included before the _FILE_OFFSET_BITS macro is set! (use rose.h first...)"
#endif
```

This causes the configure script to error out:

```
checking rose.h usability... no
checking rose.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: rose.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: rose.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: rose.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: rose.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: rose.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for rose.h... no
configure: error: A Working Rose installation is required. (Missing rose.h.)
```

Question: Is there a way to tell AC_CHECK_HEADER to create the include for rose.h loosely before the include for sys/stat.h?

Offending autoconf scripture:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(
  [rose.h],
  [],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR(A Working Rose installation is required. (Missing rose.h.))]
)
```

Pertinent config.log output:

```
configure:3995: $? = 0
configure:4013: result: yes
configure:4032: checking rose.h usability
configure:4032: g++ -std=c++11 -c -fPIC -Wall -Wno-deprecated -Wextra -O3  -DUSE_CBC  conftest.cpp >&5
In file included from /home/username/.local/opt/rose/include/rose/sage3basic.h:38:0,
                 from /home/username/.local/opt/rose/include/rose/sage3basic.hhh:4,
                 from /home/username/.local/opt/rose/include/rose/rose.h:10,
                 from conftest.cpp:56:
/home/username/.local/opt/rose/include/rose/fileoffsetbits.h:16:2: error: #error "sys/stat.h should not have been included before the _FILE_OFFSET_BITS macro is set! (use rose.h first...)"
 #error "sys/stat.h should not have been included before the _FILE_OFFSET_BITS macro is set! (use rose.h first...)"
  ^
configure:4032: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "project"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "project"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "version-0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "project version-0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define HAVE_CXX11 1
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_ISL_VERSION_H 1
| #define HAVE_LINEAR_SOLVER_LINEAR_SOLVER_H 1
| #define HAVE_LIBORTOOLS 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdio.h>
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
| # include <sys/types.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
| # include <sys/stat.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef STDC_HEADERS
| # include <stdlib.h>
| # include <stddef.h>
| #else
| # ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
| #  include <stdlib.h>
| # endif
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRING_H
| # if !defined STDC_HEADERS && defined HAVE_MEMORY_H
| #  include <memory.h>
| # endif
| # include <string.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H
| # include <strings.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
| # include <inttypes.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
| # include <stdint.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
| # include <unistd.h>
| #endif
| #include <rose.h>
configure:4032: result: no
configure:4032: checking rose.h presence
configure:4032: g++ -std=c++11 -E  conftest.cpp
configure:4032: $? = 0
configure:4032: result: yes
configure:4032: WARNING: rose.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure:4032: WARNING: rose.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure:4032: WARNING: rose.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure:4032: WARNING: rose.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure:4032: WARNING: rose.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure:4032: checking for rose.h
configure:4032: result: no
configure:4039: error: A Working Rose installation is required. (Missing rose.h.)

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_cxx_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_header_inttypes_h=yes
ac_cv_header_isl_version_h=yes
ac_cv_header_linear_solver_linear_solver_h=yes
ac_cv_header_memory_h=yes
ac_cv_header_rose_h=no
ac_cv_header_stdc=yes
ac_cv_header_stdint_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdlib_h=yes
ac_cv_header_string_h=yes
ac_cv_header_strings_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_stat_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_types_h=yes
ac_cv_header_unistd_h=yes
ac_cv_lib_ortools___include__linear_solver_linear_solver_h___include__string__=yes
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_EGREP='/bin/grep -E'
ac_cv_path_GREP=/bin/grep
ac_cv_prog_CXXCPP='g++ -std=c++11 -E'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CXX=g++
ac_cv_prog_cxx_g=yes
ac_cv_search_isl_version=-lisl
ax_cv_cxx_compile_cxx11=no
ax_cv_cxx_compile_cxx11__std_cpp11=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='g++ -std=c++11'
CXXCPP='g++ -std=c++11 -E'
CXXFLAGS='-fPIC -Wall -Wno-deprecated -Wextra -O3  -DUSE_CBC'
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/bin/grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
GREP='/bin/grep'
HAVE_CXX11='1'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS='-lortools -lisl '
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT='o'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='project'
PACKAGE_STRING='project version-0.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='project'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='version-0.1'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PYTHON=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
UNZIP=''
_PYPY_maybe=''
_PYTHON2_maybe=''
_PYTHON_maybe=''
_UNZIP_maybe=''
ac_ct_CXX='g++'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "project"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "project"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "version-0.1"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "project version-0.1"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define HAVE_CXX11 1
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_ISL_VERSION_H 1
#define HAVE_LINEAR_SOLVER_LINEAR_SOLVER_H 1
#define HAVE_LIBORTOOLS 1

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: `sys/stat.h` is a standard header file. If something needs to be included ***before*** a standard header file, that something has to be fundamentally broken in some way. Whatever this `rose.h` is trying to do, it's doing it wrong.

Comment: You seem to feel strongly about this design decision. Feel free to open an issue on the [Rose Compiler github](https://github.com/rose-compiler/rose). The code in question is [rose/src/frontend/SageIII/fileoffsetbits.h:15](https://github.com/rose-compiler/rose/blob/43c77481d0801ac122f74a778a35e2a074032d1f/src/frontend/SageIII/fileoffsetbits.h#L15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [`AC_CHECK_HEADERS` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.61/html_node/Generic-Headers.html) a little more closely, I have figured a slightly hackey way make this work for me. The `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` macro has an optional includes parameter, where you can write code (usually include directives, I assume) that is inserted before the include directive for your test.

Here you can write lots of "fun" things, like an `#undef` directive to undefine the `HAVE_SYS_STAT_H` symbol, which guards the include of `sys/stat.h`, and then include the default includes with [`AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.61/html_node/Default-Includes.html#Default-Includes)

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(
  [rose.h],
  [],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR(A Working Rose installation is required. (Missing rose.h.))],
  [
    [ #undef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H ]
    AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT
  ]
)
```

Depending on how correct/realistic you want your check to be, this may not work for you. I happen to know that `sys/stat.h` is included later on in `rose.h` and find this solution to solve my particular problem quite nicely *and* in a realistic way.

However, this hack can also be used to reorder includes. In the broadest sense, you could include the test header before all of the default includes:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(
  [rose.h],
  [],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR(A Working Rose installation is required. (Missing rose.h.))],
  [
    [ 
    #include <rose.h> 
    ]
    AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT
  ]
)
```

or mask out problematic includes:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(
  [rose.h],
  [],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR(A Working Rose installation is required. (Missing rose.h.))],
  [
    [
    #ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
    # define REDEF_HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
    # undef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
    #endif
    ]

    AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT

    [
    #include <rose.h>

    #ifdef REDEF_HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
    # define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
    #endif
    ]

    AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT
  ]
)
```

or manually order all includes you feel are necessary to your liking:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(
  [rose.h],
  [],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR(A Working Rose installation is required. (Missing rose.h.))],
  [
    [
    #include <stdio.h>
    #ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
    # include <sys/types.h>
    #endif

    #include <rose.h>

    #ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
    # include <sys/stat.h>
    #endif
    #ifdef STDC_HEADERS
    # include <stdlib.h>
    # include <stddef.h>
    #else
    # ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
    #  include <stdlib.h>
    # endif
    #endif
    #ifdef HAVE_STRING_H
    # if !defined STDC_HEADERS && defined HAVE_MEMORY_H
    #  include <memory.h>
    # endif
    # include <string.h>
    #endif
    #ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H
    # include <strings.h>
    #endif
    #ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
    # include <inttypes.h>
    #endif
    #ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
    # include <stdint.h>
    #endif
    #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
    # include <unistd.h>
    #endif
    ]
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the macro [`AC_SYS_LARGEFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/System-Services.html) before `AC_CHECK_HEADER` may solve they underlying issue.

The `rose.h` header appears to define LFS parameters, but that should *not* be done in headers, because different translation units of the same binary should not be using different LFS settings (as they would use different ABIs), and the header risks doing exactly that.

At any rate, using `AC_SYS_LARGEFILE` ensures you have the right LFS parameters for largefile set before anything gets included, and then the `#error` won't trigger.

Comment: Unfortunately the error is not triggered by not having the LFS parameter set in a certain way at a certain time. It is triggered by the existence of the _SYS_STAT_H symbol.

Having tried your solution, the error remains.